# Quotes error in Google chart "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I know this question has been asked many times but I have not really found a solution for my code.
I choose supplier and year and i want to display a list of all products.
For some suppliers it works but for others no.

After a many tests I found that my code works for all suppliers except suppliers name with quotes and acccents.

Here is my error:

> "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {
        packages: ["corechart"]
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Month', 'Product', 'Items'],
            <?php foreach ($my_data as $a => $b): ?> ['<?php echo $month[$b['
                month ']]?>', <?php echo $b['product'] ?>, <?php echo $b['items'] ?>,
            ],
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'supplier',
            hAxis: {
                title: 'product supplier',
                titleTextStyle: {
                    color: '#333'
                }
            },
            vAxis: {
                minValue: 0
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

This's my query :

```
 if(isset($_POST['$value1'] ))
    {

    $month = array('','January','February ','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
    $value1 = $_POST['$value1'] ;
    $value2 = $_POST['$value1'] ;
    $sql="  SELECT

                name,
                count(items),
                MONTH(created_at) as month,
                YEAR(created_at) as year,
                sum(product) as product

            FROM `supplier_product`
            where 
                name = '".$value1."' and YEAR(date.created_at) = '".$value2."'
                GROUP BY name,month
                ORDER BY month ASC
        ";
```

This my code PHP :

```
            <label for="supplier"> Select name : </label>
                                        <select name = "value1" id="sup">
                                            <?php
                                            $sql = "SELECT name FROM supplier_product";

                                            $req = $mydatabase->prepare($sql);
                                            $req->execute();
                                            $data = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                            foreach ($data as $a => $b):

                                            ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo utf8_encode($v['name']); ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($v['name']); ?></option>

                                             <?php
                                            endforeach;
                                                ?>
                                        </select>
                                        <select name= "value2">
                                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                            <option value="2014">2013</option>
                                            <option value="2014">2012</option>
                                            <option value="2014">2011</option>
                                            <option value="2014">2010</option>
                                            <option value="2014">2019</option>
                                        </select>
```

Help me please.
Many Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution of my question I added `addslashes` and `utf8_decode` it works now.

```php
$value1 = addslashes(utf8_decode($_POST['value1 ']));
```

Comment: Nice. It will help people in the future.  But the solution was impossible to figure out.

Comment: @davidkonrad yeah on first time I didn't think that the answer will be utf8_decode.

Answer (score -1):

Put your `php` variables in `javascript` variables, then [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) them as integers and it should work. `Google Charts` cannot perform calculations with strings.

EDIT: added example.
I was thinking about something like this(note i meant converting to integers only numbers not names). Seems like your problem is different thought.

```
var month = parseInt(<?= $month; ?>, 10);
```

EDIT2: added second example.

```
var products = [];
//your loop here
products[key] = <?= $b['product']; ?>;
products[key].replace(/["']/g, "");
//end loop
```

And then use the `javascript` variable 'products' in your charts.

Comment: Thank u for ur answer. My code works for all suppliers except suppliers name with quotes and acccents.

Comment: i know this question have been asked many times but my problem is different, my code work for a lot of suppliers but if the name of supplier contains quotes like that: "h'efkfk tmps" it display for me this error "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"

Comment: @Sarah Try removing quotes inside the name. Maybe those are your problem.

Comment: Yeah i know my problem are the quotes in the name of suppliers it works when supplier name dosen't contain quotes. I can't remove it in database i don't have a permission.

Comment: @Sarah Try removing them then with a `Regex` expression. The following should work.
`YourVarHere.replace(/["']/g, "");`

Comment: I can't remove anything in database.

Comment: It's not removing anything from the database. You take your result from your database, store it in a variable and then remove the quotes inside.
If you MUST display quotes on your chart names you can try adding a backslash before it.